# "I met where, whom" or "I met whom, where"

Tags: word-order

there is a 'word-order' quastion. Usage of pronoun "who" and adverb "where" in one sentence, example:

> - ...since **I met in Kalamazoo that artist**, he came up to me and said...

or

> - ...since **I met that artist in Kalamazoo**, he came up to me and said...

Could the first variant be acceptable?
Thank You very much.

Comment: meet + person + place. The other does not work.

Comment: (also) meet + object + place + time expression "I met him at university **several years ago**" (without "since")

Comment: Did you write the example yourself, or is a quote?

Comment: Please provide the full sentence. I find the presence of *since* jarring with the rest of the fragment. …since I met John, he *came* up to me... not quite right, unless "since" is used to mean *because / for that reason*?

Comment: @JamesK It's my example, not a quote

Comment: @Mari-LouA thank you

** ...and if there were no wars, that is all I need **
** since I met in Amsterdam that hippie-wizard, he came up to me and said: **

Comment: The construction is not quite right, try replacing *since* with *when* as in “… **when** I **first met**  that hippie **who** came up to me and said* ...” .

Comment: Andrew, why are you repeating a structure I explained does not work?? Since I met that hippie-wizard in Amsterdam, he came up to me etc. Since can also be because.

Comment: Ezra Pound, ["Poet in Exile" (1964)](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Poet_in_Exile/zxoNAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22met+in+paris+a%22&pg=PA219&printsec=frontcover) - *In 1919 **I met in Paris a quiet little man,** Ambassador at the time, whom my father remembered thirty - five years before in the act of reaching for a revolver to help out his partner*

Comment: @Lambie sorry, my fault, mistype

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, that should be: I met, in Paris, a quiet little man etc. But that does not show standard usage, does it?

Comment: @Lambie: Unbelievable! You're gonna tell *Ezra Pound* he doesn't know how to punctuate his deathless prose? And someone else *upvotes* you!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Those are words by the author, not by Pound. The previous sentence to that one is quoted as being  him.  The author of that book writes in the first person. In any event, were one speaking or reading that text, there would be a pause such that "in Paris" would indeed sound like there are commas around it.

Comment: @Lambie: Okay, well maybe he's not Ezra Pound, but [Charles S. Peirce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Sanders_Peirce) has credentials, and he wrote much the same: [*I met in New York an old friend of mine, a Frenchman, who told me how he had known very well the elder Alexandre Dumas...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22met+in+new+york+an+old+friend%22) I don't see why you're so insistent that such utterances *require* the optional "adverb of place" to be set off by commas / pauses. It reads / sounds fine to me without.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you really want to tell learners that it's ok to put the adverb of place right after the verb and in that position? Wouldn't that be like "advanced literary writing" for advanced plus learners? In today's context, in speech, it would be considered a mistake unless it were some sort of fireside or literary chat.  It just is not a **usual** collocation.

Comment: @Lambie: Call it "advanced literary writing" if you like. The OP here already ***knows*** that at the very least, ***where, whom*** is "unusual" compared to ***whom, where*** - he's asking whether the former is *ever* "acceptable". And obviously it ***is***, but I'm certainly not suggesting learners in general should make a habit of using the unusual sequence. I just don't think learners should be misled into assuming that uncommon stylistic choices are *by definition* [syntactically] "incorrect".

Answer (score 1):

Generally, locative prepositional phrases such as "in Kalamazoo"  come after the direct object of the verb.  For the verb "met" in this example, the direct object is "that artist".   So only the second sentence is "correct" English.  If the prepostitional phrase is inserted between the verb and object (for poetic or stylistic reasons) it would normally be set-off by commas or brackets:

> I met (in Kalamazoo) that artist...

Sometimes, prepositional phrases can also be placed at the start of the sentence.  That would not be possible here, as it would interfere with the word "since".

Comment: And I can't think of any exceptions off the top of my head.

Comment: I find the OP's usage of *since* jarring. Do they mean "because" or "ago/from that moment"?

Comment: It's a *stylistic choice*. Just because we nearly always choose one sequence doesn't mean the other is "incorrect". It's just "the road less travelled".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I edited.

Comment: I assume that when Ezra Pound wrote the sentence I linked to under the question, he figured it was the lesser of two evils. The "default" sequence for multiple consecutive adverbial elements would have given *In 1919 I met a quiet little man, Ambassador at the time, **in Paris** whom my father remembered...* Or even worse, ***in Paris*** could end up right at the end of the sentence! Which is okay with *I met a man who I knew in Paris*, but there's a limit to how long the reader / audience can hang on waiting for that final locative prepositional phrase! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The most natural to me would be: In 1919 in Paris,  I met a quiet little man, Ambassador at the time, despite two ins. I would say that statistically, not putting the place after the verb is literary. And not used in speech, and not really useful for a learner in that sense...